# Display Full Screen Image of Instagram Thumbnail

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am building my first Android App to download Images from Instagram API and up till now I am successful to achieve my first major task. Now I want to display full screen image of Thumbnail images received from Insta API but I am struggling to find the method/API Call. A quick clue or suggestion would be really helpful.

```
                    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser
                        .getJSONFromUrlByGet("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token="
                                + Token);
                JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                if (data != null) {
                    for (int data_i = 0; data_i < data.length(); data_i++) {
                        JSONObject data_obj = data.getJSONObject(data_i);

                        JSONObject images_obj = data_obj
                                .getJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail_obj = images_obj
                                .getJSONObject(TAG_THUMBNAIL);

                        String str_url = thumbnail_obj.getString(TAG_URL);
                        imageThumbList.add(str_url);
```

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine On Image click.

Comment: What do you mean by "full screen name of instagram thumbnail"?

Comment: @korrekorre I mean larger image of that Thumbnail in a new screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. It seems that you've got the image URL and now you want to display it somehow. To start with you need something to display the image in.

Use an ImageView like this in your view xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then you need to download the image and put it into the ImageView. This can be done in multiple ways but I really recommend using a external library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) for this. It's really simple and looks something like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(str_url).into(imageView);
```

Good luck!

Comment: No thats not what I am looking for. When a user click on a thumbnail it should open a larger image of that small one in a new activity so I need to know how can I fetch the details of that Thumbnail and then use it later. I think it would be a URL but I dont know how to fetch it.

Comment: Ok. So then you need to create a new activity that contains the ImageView and start that one by using startActivity() in your current activity. When you start the new activity you pass an intent and in that intent you can add extra data such as the image url. More info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: In the request response it seems that you have all information you need, according to: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed. For example, you have 3 different image sizes: low_resolution, thumbnail and standard_resolution which should be sufficient. Just pass the URL as a bundle to the new activity and then download it there by using Picasso for example.

Comment: Yes thats right and we are almost there. How can i fetch the URL/ID of the user clicked Thumbnail?

Comment: You already have it? Instead of passing around URLs you should create an object representing an Image that contains both the 'thumbnail' url and the 'standard_resolution' url.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the clue I was looking for. Really appreciate your effort.